# Angular *ngIf statement to check if array is empty on a search page only works once

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ng-if

I have a UI for my Springboot application to display the contents of a connected database. Within the UI is a search page where users can search for items in the database according to date ranges, names of items, etc. In terms of the UI, I have an array called "temp", which I populate with information of whatever the user has just searched (for the purposes of printing it out on the search page).

On the HTML side of my search page I have added the following inline code (in the form of an *ngIf statement) to see weather or not the temp array is empty, and if it is I will print out a message on the page saying that the user's search has yielded zero results.

```
<div>
<h6 *ngIf = "temp.length == 0" style = color:red>Your search yielded zero results.</h6>
</div>
```

The if statement works perfectly for the first iteration of the search, as long as the user's search does not yield any results that red message will show on the page. The problem arises when the user finally does input a valid search (which will of course lead to no red message, and all of the results from the search showing on the page), then when they do an invalid search directly after the valid search, then the message does not show up.

To conclude, as soon as the user searches for something that actually has results, and then they search for something that has no results, my red message will not show up even though it should because the if statement is checking for searches with no results. However, the if statement works perfectly as long as the user doesn't search for a valid search, and then subsequently an invalid search.

Comment: You should at least show us how the variable `temp` is modified during the interactions

Comment: is `temp` your main array? the one will all the info

Comment: sounds like you are not clearing the temp array on a new search

Comment: @MarkHomer you are 100% correct. I am now clearing my temp array after every search and it is working properly now. Thanks!